# Performance of drawRect

Tags: iphone, ios, drawrect

Hey guys just a quick question about the performance of `drawRect:` as I've noticed a lot of topics with people complaining about performance issues.

In my App, I need to draw ~150 squares overtop some underlaying views. Obviously this many calls isn't going to have a noticeable user difference, but I'm just wondering about the pros and cons going forward. Currently I'm debating two ways:

1) add a transparent UIView subclass on top with a custom `drawRect:` to facilitate the drawing

2) just add normal square subviews

As I said, using CADisplayLink there won't be any difference to the user, I'm just curious what would be more efficient? (2) is kind of a ridiculous way of doing it, adding instances with useless functionality just for appearance, but all these posts have just scared me into using `drawRect`. Is `drawRect` really that inefficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps unintuitively, `drawRect:` isn't called for every frame. In fact, if you do nothing special in your view and your view itself doesn't change, it gets called once.

You can force it to be called by calling `[myView setNeedsDisplay]`, but there usually is no reason to.

If you have a view with overlapping subviews, still for each of those views, including the superview, `drawRect:` is only called once. Then, the GPU does the compositing (blending).

A custom `drawRect:` is almost always slower (and harder) than just using UIKit the way it was intended, if UIKit already offers what you want to do.

Also don't fall into one of the biggest traps in software development, *premature optimization*. Code the most naive version, benchmark it, and if it's fast enough, it's good enough, and you can focus your energy elsewhere. Only start optimizing once you know *that* something is actually slow, and *where* and *why* it is.

Comment: Drawing in UIKit can become quite a complicated (and interesting) topic once you stick your head in, but for many things, it's not really needed. If you are a registered developer, the WWDC 2011 session videos 121 and 129 might be interesting - but as long as UIKit does what you want fast enough, there's no need to worry and overcomplicate things.

Comment: for the record, just for kicks I implemented drawing with a custom `drawRect:` (which, for my purposes needs to be called using `setNeedsDisplay` on a CADisplayLink timer) and couldn't believe how slow it rendered - unbelievable.

Comment: The thing is, if you draw every frame, you're (probably) doing a lot of stuff on the CPU, whereas if you just use UIKit, each layer is (mostly) just drawn into a buffer once (they essentially become static images), and the GPU is very optimized to move those around, blend them over each other, etc.

Comment: (This is also the reason why zooming in a `UIScrollView` is so fast: It just sets the transform for the subview, and applying transformation matrices is something GPUs are heavily optimized for. The view itself doesn't get redrawn at all! It just gets displayed differently by the GPU, which costs almost nothing)